# Is it possible to reduce the speed and frequency of a light wave to zero in a liquid medium?

Tags: special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, speed-of-light, refraction, frequency

Assume that two mirrors are located in a huge liquid medium – say, deep down on an ocean floor – with a refractive index of $n'$ as measured by an observer $A$ standing on the beach platform at rest WRT the liquid. One of the mirrors is at rest WRT $A$, and the other mirror recedes from $A$ at $v$. Remember that the mirrors are parallel to each other both perpendicular to the velocity vector.

Now, suppose that a tiny laser diode attached to the lowest part of the first mirror sends a photon towards the moving one at an angle nearly perpendicular to the surfaces of the mirrors. The photon, after being bounced between the mirrors for $i$ times, is received by a detector set on an upper side of the same mirror. [See the Figure.] Each time the photon hits the moving mirror, its speed reduces as measured by observer $A$.

Can we say that, from the perspective of $A$, the velocity of the photon, complying with the relativistic velocity addition, reduces each time it hits the moving mirror till the speed, possibly along with the light frequency, approaches zero if the number of bounces is great enough? Is it correct to use the relativistic velocity addition formula in this example?

According to the figure, $c'_1$ is calculated to be:

$$c'_1=\frac{c}{n'} \tag{1}$$

Using the relativistic velocity addition formula, for $c'_2$ we can write:

$$c'_2=\frac{c'_1-v}{1-\frac{vc'_1}{c^2}}=\frac{\frac{c}{n'}-v}{1-\frac{v}{n'c}} \tag{2}$$

Similarly, for $c'_3$, $c'_4$, and $c'_i$, we have:

$$c'_3=\frac{c'_2-v}{1-\frac{vc'_2}{c^2}} \tag{3}$$

$$c'_4=\frac{c'_3-v}{1-\frac{vc'_3}{c^2}} \tag{4}$$

$$c'_i=\frac{c'_{i-1}-v}{1-\frac{vc'_{i-1}}{c^2}} \tag{5}$$

As we see, we can arbitrarily reduce the speed of light if we repeat the calculation enough. Does this mean that the speed of light can be as slow as a turtle in a medium by this means? Do the accurate calculations become more complicated than those done here by considering the fact that the refractive index varies as a function of *frequency* as well as velocity $v$?

[image: Bouncing Photon]

Comment: “Each time the photon hits the moving mirror, its speed reduces as measured by observer A”. This is not correct. The light moves at v=c/n at all times in this scenario. It Doppler shifts when it hits the mirror, it does not slow unless the index of refraction is frequency dependent.

Comment: @Dale Maybe you are right, but how can you assure me of this?

Comment: The definition of the index of refraction is v=c/n. If the definition doesn’t assure you then there is little I can do about it.

Comment: @Dale To understand my claim better, consider the speed of light from the viewpoint of the observer at rest in the frame of the moving mirror. He indeed observes that the liquid, as well as the left mirror and the diode, is in motion at $v$. Therefore, it is expected that the speed of light reduces each time it hits the left mirror complying with the relativistic addition formula as stated here: https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Light_in_moving_media

Comment: You have that backwards. Since the right hand mirror is moving at +v in A’s frame the fluid is moving at -v in the right hand mirror’s frame. So  in that frame the light goes faster after reflection as it travels in the same direction as the fluid. Anyway, I don’t expect that I will convince you, but it is so as per the page you cited, relativistic velocity addition, and the Fizeau experiment.

Comment: @Dale I meant the left-hand mirror. You are right for the right-hand mirror, however, I think the light moves slower whenever it reflects from the left mirror. The problem is how we can apply the relativistic addition formula for these cases. From the viewpoint of the moving mirror, it is expected that $c_1=\frac{c/n'-v}{1-v/(n'c)}$ as the photon leaves the diode, but what can we say for when it reflects from the right mirror: This one: $c_2=\frac{c/n'+v}{1+v/(n'c)}$ or this one: $c_2=\frac{c_1+v}{1+vc_1/c^2}=c/n'$? I think, however, the second one is more probable.

Comment: Because the velocity of the light reflecting from the left mirror would become $c_3=\frac{c_2-v}{1-vc_2/c^2}=\frac{c/n'-v}{1-v/(n'c)}$, and again for $c_4$ we have: $c_4=\frac{c_3+v}{1+vc_3/c^2}=c/n'$.

Comment: The relativistic velocity addition formula is between the v=c/n light in the rest frame of the fluid and the velocity of the fluid in another frame. It has nothing whatsoever to do with the mirror. Think of this: in Maxwell’s equations we know where to plug in the permittivity and permeability of the fluid, but where in Maxwell’s equations do you put the velocity of the last mirror it bounced off once it is away from that mirror? (Spoiler: nowhere, it is irrelevant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider Maxwell's equations in a linear transparent medium without free currents or charges:
$$\nabla \cdot \vec E = 0$$
$$\nabla \cdot \vec B = 0$$
$$\nabla \times \vec E = -\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \vec B$$
$$\nabla \times \vec B = \mu \epsilon \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \vec E$$
Which can be reduced to:
$$\left(\frac{1}{\mu \epsilon} \nabla^2 - \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\right)\vec E = 0$$

Since $\mu \epsilon = \mu_r \epsilon_r \mu_0 \epsilon_0 = n^2/c^2$ this represents a wave moving at a speed $v=c/n$.

In other words, from Maxwell's equations the speed of the wave is determined entirely by the electromagnetic properties of the medium, as summarized by the refractive index $n$. Neither the speed of the source nor the speed of any intervening reflective surface are involved. As long as Maxwell's equations are valid in a medium, the speed of the wave depends only on the electromagnetic properties of the medium itself.

Generally, the relative permittivity and permeability of a material are measured in the rest frame of the material, and thus the refractive index describes the $v=c/n$ of the wave in the rest frame of the material. Therefore, to obtain the velocity in another frame one simply applies relativistic velocity addition using the known speed of the light in the rest frame of the medium and the speed of the medium in another frame to obtain the speed of light in the other frame. This is consistent with the famous Fizeau experiment which predated relativity but provided probably the first evidence supporting relativistic velocity addition.

Thus it is incorrect that "Each time the photon hits the moving mirror, its speed reduces as measured by observer A". Upon recognizing this the rest of the problem disappears.

> Do the accurate calculations become more complicated than those done here by considering the fact that the refractive index varies as a function of frequency as well as velocity v?

Yes, the light will Doppler shift (in the stationary mirror's frame) upon hitting the moving mirror. As a result, if $n$ is a function of frequency then the speed will change. As the amount of Doppler shift depends on the speed of the mirror, and the frequency depends on the Doppler shift, and the refractive index depends on the frequency, and the speed of the light wave depends on the refractive index, then it is true that (indirectly) the speed of the light wave depends on the speed of the mirror. However the relationship is not as simple as velocity addition, but rather follows the causal chain outlined above. In the absence of a frequency dependence of $n$ there is no dependence of the speed of light on the velocity of the mirror.

Comment: Comprehensive. Thanks. I found one of my own old drafts in which I'd applied the correct calculations as to this subject as you mentioned. I'd just forgot it for a while!

Comment: Excellent! Yes, that happens to us all at some point.

Answer (score 1):

In other words, does speed of light (after reflection) depend on speed of mirrors as well as speed of water or not? Clearly the answer is NO.

Let's redo this experiment, but this time in space not water. Simply enough we can see that speed of light will be c no matter what. Wavelength is the only thing which is affected by velocity of mirrors and that's because of Doppler effect.

Water is no exception(why would it be?). Light just doesn't care about what it sees at boundaries. Its speed from A perspective will be $c/n$ before and after reflections. From perspective of moving mirror however, light's speed will oscillate between $\frac{c/n-v}{1-\frac{cv}{nc^2}}$ (before reflection) and $\frac{c/n+v}{1+\frac{cv}{nc^2}}$ (after reflection) where $v$ is speed of water.

Comment: It is possible that the speeds are alternatively $\frac{c/n'-v}{1-v/(n'c)}$ and $c/n'$ as measured by the observer in the moving mirror's rest frame.

Comment: I think that *light in medium* is no longer "light", but rather is physically equal to a fast-moving *object*, and hence, I anticipate that its velocity complies with the relativistic velocity addition formula regardless of whether the medium is stationary or moving. Therefore, I think that $A$ must, too, somehow be able to apply the relativistic velocity addition, yet its consequences are slightly vague to me.

Comment: It does comply with the relativistic velocity addition. That has nothing to do with the mirrors. You relativistically add the velocity of the light wrt the fluid and the velocity of the fluid to get the velocity of the light in a frame where the fluid is moving.